# HMENU Browse - show linkWrap even if ATagTitle is empty (TYPO3 8.7.x)

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I use the following Typoscript for a special menu. Of course there is no linkWrap right now if `ATagTitle.dataWrap` is empty. What is the best way to have `&nbsp;` as content of the `ATagTitle.dataWrap` if `{field:title}` is empty so that the `linkWrap` is used?

```
  [treeLevel = 3,4,5]
        lib.navHorizon = COA
        lib.navHorizon {
            stdWrap.wrap = <nav class="row nav_horizontal">|</nav>
            10 = HMENU
            10 {
                special = browse
                special {
                    items = prev
                }

            1 = TMENU
            1.noBlur = 1
            1.NO {
                ATagTitle.dataWrap = {field:title}
                linkWrap = <div class="d-none d-md-block col-4 nav_prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> |</div>    
            }
        }

        25 = HMENU
        25 {
            special = browse
            special {
                items = up
            }

            1 = TMENU
            1.noBlur = 1
            1.NO {
                ATagTitle.dataWrap = {field:title}
                linkWrap = <div class="d-none d-md-block col-4 nav_up">|</div>
            }
        }

        20 = HMENU
        20 {
            special = browse
            special {
                items = next
            }

            1 = TMENU
            1.noBlur = 1
            1.NO {
                ATagTitle.dataWrap = {field:title}
                linkWrap = <div class="d-none d-md-block col-4 order-3 nav_next">| <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></div>
            }
        }
    }

[global]
```

Extended explanation:
I have a row with three columns. If the first column containing the link to the previous page is empty, the HTML for the column is also missing, so the layout is no longer correct.

Comment: `{field:title}` is empty? It's the page title. I don't think you can create a page without a title (in a regular work flow)

Comment: When there no previous page the page title in the menu is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your additional information I understand the problem is not that the title is empty, but that there's no page at all. So if there's not previous page, it will not "execute" `lib.navHorizon.10.1` at all.

You can fix this by not setting the wrap on the link, but on the HMENU:

```
10 = HMENU
10 {
  special = browse
  special {
    items = prev
  }

  wrap = <div class="d-none d-md-block col-4 nav_prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> |</div>    

  1 = TMENU
  1.noBlur = 1
  1.NO {
    ATagTitle.dataWrap = {field:title}
  }
}
```

This will ensure the wrap is always rendered, even if there's no page.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't solve my problem.I will extend the explanation of my problem to make it more understandable.

Comment: that's perfect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

as (nearly) each object in typoscript has stdWrap functionality you can 'wrap' the dataWrap:

```
ATagTitle.dataWrap = {field:title}
ATagTitle.dataWrap.ifEmpty = &nbsp;
```

Comment: I just tried this in TYPO3 9 and it doesn't work. I think ifEmpty is resolved before {field:title} is replaced with the value in the title field, which means it won't see it as empty. Using `ATagTitle.dataWrap.field = title` does work.

Comment: if `ifEmpty` is evaluated (and replacing the content) before `{field:title}` is resolved it is a very bad bug. In your case the usage of `.field` is possible as you only have the field content in your wrap, but what if the usage needs more? then it would fail.

Comment: for a later evaluation of `ifEmpty` you could insert an additional layer of `stdWrap` with: `ATagTitle.dataWrap.stdWrap.ifEmpty = &nbsp;`